# Restyling traces using plotlyProxy in a scatterplot is unstable when points are colored according to category

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly, plotly.js

I have a Shiny app that builds a scatterplot and highlights the clicked points by restyling the marker outline via plotlyProxy.
The app also subsets the data and moves the entries corresponding to the clicked points from the original "Data table" to an "Outlier table".

This seems to work fine when the markers are all the same color, or when they are colored by a continuous variable. But when I color the points by a categorical variable (like "Species"), it has a weird behavior, restyling a marker from each category instead of the clicked one. The data subsets correctly.

I think the restyle function should update all traces unless specified otherwise, so I am not sure where exactly lies the problem.

Here is my code:

```
library(plotly)
library(DT)

    ui <- fluidPage(
     mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
       div(
        column(
            width = 2,
            uiOutput('chartOptions')),
        column(width = 5,
               h3("Scatter plot"),
               plotlyOutput("scatterplot"),
               verbatimTextOutput("click")
        )
      )
),
    hr(),
    div(
        column(width = 6,
               h2("Data Table"),
               div(
                   DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table_keep"),
                   style = "height:auto; overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;")),
        
        column(width = 6,
               h2("Outlier Data"),
               div(
                   DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table_outliers"),
                   style = "height:auto; overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;"))
    )
 ))
server <- function(input, output, session){
  datasetInput <- reactive({
     df <- iris
       return(df)
  })

output$chartOptions <- renderUI({#choose variables to plot
    if(is.null(datasetInput())){}
    else {
        list(
            selectizeInput("xAxisSelector", "X Axis Variable",
                           colnames(datasetInput())),
            selectizeInput("yAxisSelector", "Y Axis Variable",
                           colnames(datasetInput())),
            selectizeInput("colorBySelector", "Color By:",
                           c(c("Do not color",colnames(datasetInput()))))
        )      
    }
})

vals <- reactiveValues(#define reactive values for:
    data = NULL,
    data_keep = NULL,
    data_exclude = NULL)

observe({
    vals$data <- datasetInput()
    vals$data_keep <- datasetInput()
    
})

## Datatable 
output$table_keep <- renderDT({
    vals$data_keep      
},options = list(pageLength = 5))

output$table_outliers <- renderDT({
    vals$data_exclude      
},options = list(pageLength = 5))

# mechanism for managing selected points
keys <- reactiveVal()

observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "outliers", priority = "event"), {
    req(vals$data)
    is_outlier <- NULL
    key_new <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "outliers")$key
    key_old <- keys()
    if (key_new %in% key_old){
        keys(setdiff(key_old, key_new))
    } else {
        keys(c(key_new, key_old))
    }
    is_outlier <- rownames(vals$data) %in% keys()
    
    vals$data_keep <- vals$data[!is_outlier, ]
    vals$data_exclude <- vals$data[is_outlier, ]
    
    plotlyProxy("scatterplot", session) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke(
            "restyle", 
            list(marker.line = list(
                    color = as.vector(ifelse(is_outlier,'black','grey')),
                    width = 2
                
            ))
        )
})

observeEvent(event_data("plotly_doubleclick", source = "outliers"), {
    req(vals$data)
    keys(NULL)
    vals$data_keep <- vals$data
    vals$data_exclude <- NULL
    plotlyProxy("scatterplot", session) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke(
            "restyle", 
            list(marker.line = list(
                    color = 'grey',
                    width = 2
                )
            ))
        
})

output$scatterplot <- renderPlotly({
    req(vals$data,input$xAxisSelector,input$yAxisSelector)
    dat <- vals$data
    key <- rownames(vals$data)
    x <- input$xAxisSelector
    y <- input$yAxisSelector
    
    if(input$colorBySelector != "Do not color"){
        color <-  dat[, input$colorBySelector] 
    }else{
        color <- "orange"
    }
    
    scatterplot <- dat %>%
        plot_ly(x = dat[,x], y = dat[,y], source = "outliers") %>%
        add_markers(key = key,color = color,
                    marker = list(size = 10, line = list(
                        color = 'grey',
                        width = 2
                    ))) %>%
        layout(showlegend = FALSE)
    
    return(scatterplot)
})


output$click <- renderPrint({#click event data
    d <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "outliers")
    if (is.null(d)) "click events appear here (double-click to clear)" else d
})
}
 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your above code is that no `traceIndices` argument is provided for `restyle`. Please see [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-plotly-proxies-for-multiple-traces-work-in-shiny/42593/2).

In your example, once you switch coloring to the factor `Species` plotly no longer creates one trace, but three. This happens in JS so counting is done from 0 to 2.

To `restyle` those traces you can address them via curveNumber (in this case `0:2`) and pointNumber (50 data points in each trace `0:49`)

With a single trace your example works as your `key` and your trace have the same length (150).

As your provided code is pretty long I just focused on the "Species" problem. It won't work in all other cases, but you should be able to deduce a more general approach from it:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      div(
        column(
          width = 2,
          uiOutput('chartOptions')),
        column(width = 5,
               h3("Scatter plot"),
               plotlyOutput("scatterplot"),
               verbatimTextOutput("click")
        )
      )
    ),
    hr(),
    div(
      column(width = 6,
             h2("Data Table"),
             div(
               DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table_keep"),
               style = "height:auto; overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;")),
      
      column(width = 6,
             h2("Outlier Data"),
             div(
               DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table_outliers"),
               style = "height:auto; overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;"))
    )
  ))
server <- function(input, output, session){
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    df <- iris
    df$is_outlier <- FALSE
    return(df)
  })
  
  output$chartOptions <- renderUI({#choose variables to plot
    if(is.null(datasetInput())){}
    else {
      list(
        selectizeInput("xAxisSelector", "X Axis Variable",
                       colnames(datasetInput())),
        selectizeInput("yAxisSelector", "Y Axis Variable",
                       colnames(datasetInput())),
        selectizeInput("colorBySelector", "Color By:",
                       c(c("Do not color",colnames(datasetInput()))))
      )      
    }
  })
  
  vals <- reactiveValues(#define reactive values for:
    data = NULL,
    data_keep = NULL,
    data_exclude = NULL)
  
  observe({
    vals$data <- datasetInput()
    vals$data_keep <- datasetInput()
    
  })
  
  ## Datatable 
  output$table_keep <- renderDT({
    vals$data_keep      
  },options = list(pageLength = 5))
  
  output$table_outliers <- renderDT({
    vals$data_exclude      
  },options = list(pageLength = 5))
  
  # mechanism for managing selected points
  keys <- reactiveVal()
  
  myPlotlyProxy <- plotlyProxy("scatterplot", session)
  
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "outliers", priority = "event"), {
    req(vals$data)
    is_outlier <- NULL
    plotlyEventData <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "outliers")
    key_new <- plotlyEventData$key
    key_old <- keys()
    if (key_new %in% key_old){
      keys(setdiff(key_old, key_new))
    } else {
      keys(c(key_new, key_old))
    }
    vals$data[keys(),]$is_outlier <- TRUE
    is_outlier <- vals$data$is_outlier
    vals$data_keep <- vals$data[!is_outlier, ]
    vals$data_exclude <- vals$data[is_outlier, ]
    print(paste("pointNumber:", plotlyEventData$pointNumber))
    print(paste("curveNumber:", plotlyEventData$curveNumber))
      plotlyProxyInvoke(
        myPlotlyProxy,
        "restyle", 
        list(marker.line = list(
          color = as.vector(ifelse(vals$data[vals$data$Species %in% vals$data[plotlyEventData$key, ]$Species, ]$is_outlier,'black','grey')),
          width = 2
        )), plotlyEventData$curveNumber
      )
  })
  
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_doubleclick", source = "outliers"), {
    req(vals$data)
    keys(NULL)
    vals$data_keep <- vals$data
    vals$data_exclude <- NULL
      plotlyProxyInvoke(
        myPlotlyProxy,
        "restyle",
        list(marker.line = list(
          color = 'grey',
          width = 2
        )
        ))

  })
  
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlotly({
    req(datasetInput(),input$xAxisSelector,input$yAxisSelector)
    dat <- datasetInput()
    key <- rownames(dat)
    x <- input$xAxisSelector
    y <- input$yAxisSelector
    
    if(input$colorBySelector != "Do not color"){
      color <-  dat[, input$colorBySelector] 
    }else{
      color <- "orange"
    }
    
    scatterplot <- dat %>%
      plot_ly(x = dat[,x], y = dat[,y], source = "outliers") %>%
      add_markers(key = key,color = color,
                  marker = list(size = 10, line = list(
                    color = 'grey',
                    width = 2
                  ))) %>%
      layout(showlegend = FALSE)
    
    return(scatterplot)
  })
  
  
  output$click <- renderPrint({#click event data
    d <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "outliers")
    if (is.null(d)) "click events appear here (double-click to clear)" else d
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: This code still appears to be unstable, highlights multiple points when clicking only one.

Comment: That's not correct - the API isn't 'unstable' you just have to provide the required information. As mentioned in the answer the `traceIndices` are provided correctly only in case of selecting `Species` (This can be generalized, but your example is far away from beeing minimal - so I focused on the main issue). I added a gif to show the behaviour. Highlighting multiple points is done when `traceIndices` is `NULL`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The clicked points are stored in the variable 'is_outlier', that is why after the double click event, which resets the outlined points, the click event will highlight the previously selected points again, so it appears that it selects multiple points. I just have to reset the variable 'is_outlier' on the double click event.

Comment: There appears to be something not working in ```if(input$colorBySelector != "Do not color"){color <-  dat[, input$colorBySelector] }else{color <- "orange"}``` . If I change 'orange' to any other color, it ignores that color. It's missed because for some reason it still defaults to orange

Answer (score 0):

As a quick workaround, to avoid creating 3 traces, I simply converted the categorical variable assigned to color to numeric, and I hid the colorbar, so the output looks like this:

```
 output$scatterplot <- renderPlotly({
    req(vals$data,input$xAxisSelector,input$yAxisSelector)
    dat <- vals$data
    key <- rownames(vals$data)
    x <- input$xAxisSelector
    y <- input$yAxisSelector
    
    if(input$colorBySelector != "Do not color"){
        color <-  as.numeric(dat[, input$colorBySelector])
    }else{
        color <- "orange"
    }
    
    scatterplot <- dat %>%
        plot_ly(x = dat[,x], y = dat[,y], source = "outliers") %>%
        add_markers(key = key,color = color, 
                    marker = list(size = 10, line = list(
                        color = 'grey',
                        width = 2
                    ))) %>%
        layout(showlegend = FALSE) %>%
        hide_colorbar()%>% 
        event_register("plotly_click")
    
    return(scatterplot)
})
```

Update:

Another solution that I found is to make a loop of plotly proxies for each trace / category in the click event.
So the click event looks like this:

```
observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "outliers", priority = "event"), {
    req(vals$data)

    is_outlier <- NULL
    key_new <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "outliers")$key
    key_old <- keys()
    #keys(c(key_new, key_old))
    if (key_new %in% key_old){
        keys(setdiff(key_old, key_new))
    } else {
        keys(c(key_new, key_old))
    }
    is_outlier <- rownames(vals$data) %in% keys()
    
    vals$data_keep <- vals$data[!is_outlier, ]
    vals$data_exclude <- vals$data[is_outlier, ]
    indices <- list()
    p <- plotlyProxy("scatterplot", session) 
         
    
    if(input$colorBySelector != "Do not color"){
        if(is.factor(vals$data[,input$colorBySelector])){
            for (i in 1:length(levels(vals$data[,input$colorBySelector]))){

                indices[[i]] <- rownames(vals$data[which(vals$data[,input$colorBySelector] == levels(vals$data[,input$colorBySelector])[i]), ])     #retrieve indices for each category
                   
                 plotlyProxyInvoke(p,
                        "restyle", 
                        list(marker.line = list(
                            color = as.vector(ifelse(is_outlier[as.numeric(indices[[i]])],'black','grey')),

                            width = 2

                        )), c(i-1)   #specify the trace (traces are indexed from 0)
                    )

            }
        }else{
            p %>%
                plotlyProxyInvoke(
                    "restyle", 
                    list(marker.line = list(
                        color = as.vector(ifelse(is_outlier,'black','grey')),
                        width = 2

                    ))
                )
        }
    }else{
        p %>%
            plotlyProxyInvoke(
                "restyle", 
                list(marker.line = list(
                    color = as.vector(ifelse(is_outlier,'black','grey')),
                    width = 2

                ))
            )
    }
    
})
```